# Handling Norwegian and Icelandic letters in Java

Tags: java, maven, unicode

In Java, 
I am receiving an text input which contains Norwegian Characters and Icelandic characters.

I get a stream and then parse it to String and assign to some variables  and again create output.

When i make output, Norwegian and Icelandic characters get distorted and get some ? or ¶ etc. Output files also get same character when opened.

I am making web project .war using Maven. What basic settings are required for Icelandic/Norwegian Text in Coding?

I get a method of setting Locale but unable to produce output using it. Locale.setDefault(new Locale("is_IS", "Iceland"));

Kindly Suggest. How to do it?

**Actual Character**: HÝS048

**Distorted Character**: HÃ?S048 (when SOUT directly) or H??S048 (when i get bytes from string and put into string object using UTF-8)

**Update** (11:13)
I have used

`CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
    encoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("d:\\try1.csv"),encoder));
    out.write(sb.toString());
    out.flush();
    out.close();`

Output: HÃƒï¿½S048

**Update** (12:41):
While reading stream from HTTP source i have used following:

```
`BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(apiURL.openStream(), "UTF-8"));`
```

It perfectly shows output on Console.
I have fetched value of CSV and put it in after logics Bean.

Now I need to create CSV file but when i get values from bean it again gives distorted text. I am using StringBuilder to append the values of bean and write it to file. :( Hope for best. Looking for ideas

Comment: too broad.  You have to consider the character set of your JSP, consider using String.getBytes ("IS") etc.

Comment: These are Java files not JSP and handling are in Java files only. How to use character sets in that?

Comment: look at the String.getBytes () method.  Also similar for InputStream - which one are you using?

Comment: Sounds like your program thinks the input stream is encoded in UTF-8 and the source of the stream thinks you're using a different encoding, or something like that.

Comment: I am getting InputStream from URL. I am fetching Input Stream like for(nextLine = csv.readNext()) and readnext() return String[]. then for (String token : nextLine) and that String token when printed or put into file all characters are distorted. Actual Character: HÝS048 (icelandic) and distorted (HÃ?S048 or H??S048)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to get data in UTF-8, print it in UTF-8 and to create file in UTF-8

Read data from URL as below:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(apiURL.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Then set it to beans or do whatever you want. While printing

```
System.out.println(new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"));
```

Then while creating file again:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("d:\\try2.csv");
writer.append(new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

This is how my problem got resolved.